# Entity specify relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, annotations

Does anyone know how I can achieve this in Entity Framework.
I know it is some kind of data annotation but I cannot work out how.

```
public class MainClass
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
        
    public int OtherClassId {get;set;}
    
    [ForeignKey("OtherClassId")]
    public OtherClass OtherClassObject {get;set;}
}


public class OtherClass
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    
    public MainClass MainClassObject {get;set;}
}
```

Table MainClass:
Columns:
Name
OtherClassId

Table OtherClass:
OtherClass

I have tried `InverseProperty` but it did not work

Comment: It seems you should put `[ForeignKey("OtherClassObject")]` to `OtherClassId ` property and remove   `[ForeignKey("OtherClassId")]` from `OtherClassObject`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the foreign key annotation on the class identifier field, if you want to implement the one to one relationship as follows:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public int MainClassId { get; set; }
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public virtual OtherClass OtherClassObject {get;set;}
}

public class OtherClass
{
    [ForeignKey("MainClass")]
    public int OtherClassId { get; set; }
    public string Name{get;set;}

    public virtual MainClass MainClassObject {get;set;}
}
```

for other types of relationships you can visit this link : https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

public virtual otherclass otherclassobject

You can reach the other class with the virtual class structure using the form.
I do not fully understand your question, but I interpreted your request in this way.